# how to create a single form in wordpress for multiple user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a WordPress website in which I need a form in which two users will fill this single form.

Like section 1 will be filled by guest and section 2 will be existing users also, I need to display the form records in the dashboard.

Also, section two must be disabled for guest users.

I am not sure how to achieve this.
[image]

Comment: Could you make your question more clear? What have you tried thus far?

Comment: @João I have tried caldera forms plugin buts not suitable

Answer (score 0):

You've got at least 2 pretty robust options.

The "free" way would be to build your own form with PHP and make use of WordPress' [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) function to show/hide the second portion. (You'll want the lower half to not even render to the page instead of just being "hidden" as a best-practice).

Another way would be to make use of the one of the arguably most powerful Form Builder plugins for WordPress: [GravityForms](https://www.gravityforms.com/). Note, I'm not affiliated with them, but my agency has used Gravity Forms for a decade and it's incredibly extensible. Like native WordPress, Gravity Forms has a ton of Hooks and Filters to modify the form, output, admin display, etc.

You could build the entire form and make use of the [`gform_pre_render`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_render/) filter to modify the form based on the value returned from [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/). The downside to this is that it's a premium plugin, but it's got an enormous community that's done some really neat things with it. An upside is that it's already got dashboard entry displays done, so you wouldn't need to do much in that vein.

Either way, you've got quite a bit of work cut out for you (whether using a custom built PHP form or a plugin), but the *logic* behind what sections to display is pretty simple, and would just be based around the `is_user_logged_in()` function.